# nodejs server connecting to mongodb when at the initialization: the server was not connected to internet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, wifi

Hello here is my problem,

I am working on a device that host a nodejs server.
this nodejs server is able to run smoothly without the wifi.
There is few rest point who need access to a database server (mongodb).

I use nodejs, mongoose, express.

my question is:
Is it possible to set up a connection to mongodb server after this initialization of the server (after a rest call for example) when at the initialization the server did not have wifi but during the before the rest call it has the wifi.

It is possible to do it when the server already has the wifi at the initialization.
But I wonder when it does not have the wifi at the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

All official MongoDB drivers establish connections and monitor the deployment in the background and will automatically handle network outages. Client objects can be created when there is no network connectivity to the deployment, connectivity can be interrupted, etc. Queries themselves of course won't work when there is no connectivity but once connectivity reappears no actions are needed by the application for the driver to start working.

In some drivers like the node one this behavior must be explicitly requested for the time being for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: I can't speak for other drivers but the node.js driver [defaults](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) to try reconnecting 30 times with a 1000ms delay between retries so won't recover automatically after the 30 retries. The buffered queries are also lost at that point.

Comment: I assume this is the deprecated legacy behavior you get when you don't request the unified topology.

Comment: Yeah you're right, using the unified topology [deprecates them](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/src/sdam/topology.ts#L69-L74)

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand, so is it a normal behavior that I can cant connect to mongoDB remote server after getting network connectivity when the node server have been launched with out network connectivity